# Python Visualization: Determining Data Attributes Visually by Mouse Hover and Click

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am rendering very large X,Y,Z scientific datasets in the lateral plane and would like to click on the results to obtain greater textual detail about the area chosen by mouse-click.

So, for example, imagine a scientific dataset which is rendered as a filled contour plot and there is a bright spot.  I would like to click on that spot to obtain a link or other textual information.

This would necessitate having another plane that would provide attribute information.

I would be most appreciative for any direction that others have used in similar cases.  I expect this problem has been solved previously so I would prefer not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to dive into matplotlib's event handling code. This allows you to take some action when you click on a piece of the plot, or press a key, or whatever. [Here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/event_handling/index.html) are the example programs on the matplotlib site that have to do with event handling.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!  I appreciate it.